# Архитектура памяти x86_64

Tags: linux

Не могу разобраться, между процессором CPU и кэшем (L1 или L2) данные передаются кэш-строкой, обычно размер 64 Байта.

Процессор запрашивает 1 байт по некоторому адресу, что происходит если данных в кэшах L1 и L2 нет?:
1) процессор выполняет запрос к основной памяти DRAM и при этом из основной памяти в сторону кэшей и CPU перемещается одна страница памяти, обычно размером 4КБ;

или
2) процессор выполняет запрос к основной памяти DRAM и при этом из основной памяти в сторону кэшей и CPU перемещается одна кэш-строка, размером 64 Байта.

Comment: По идее должна получаться строка кеша, т.е. 64 байта. Читать страницу было бы перебором

Comment: @Mike, ну почему же? Для LLC 4 кБайта не так уж и много. Если интересно, посмотрите на предлагаемую технологию CAT для Linux. https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/144196/

Comment: @0andriy А причем тут чтение целой страницы ? Кеш заполняется _перед_ тем как любая инструкция сможет воспользоваться данными. Теперь предположим, что у нас программа, которой кеш сильно не помогает, потому что она скачет по гиганскому куску памяти в почти случайном порядке (например идет двоичным поиском по региону в 1 Гб). И ради каждого разового обращения инструкция будет ждать пока загрузят 4 Кб из которых ей надо 4 байта, после чего переходит сразу к другой точке и опять ждет ...